# throw Throwable within \/.fromTryCatch - and align method types correctly

Tags: scala, scalaz

I have following existing method:

```
def test: \/[Throwable, Person] = {
  \/.fromTryCatch {
    //existing logic has potential to throw exception (from calls like .toInt) etc
    //now via following for comprehension want to combine Throwable with return type \/[Throwable,Person]
    for {
      p <- q.firstOption.\/>(new Throwable("can't find record for person with id = " + id))
    } yield p
  }
}
```

Which produces the following error:

```
type mismatch; found : scalaz.\/[Throwable,Person] (which expands to) scalaz.\/[Throwable,Person] required:Person
```

how do I align return type of the for-comprehension with type of `def test`?

Answer (score 0):

`fromTryCatch` expects a value that evaluates to `Person`, that may throw an exception.

So you don't need to wrap the exception in a `\/`, you can simply throw an exception in the `fromTryCatch` block and it will be caught and wrapped automatically.

Alternatively you can simply drop the `fromTryCatch`, since you're already materializing the exceptions in a `\/[Throwable, Person]`, e.g.

```
def test : \/[Throwable,Person] =
  for {
    p <- q.firstOption.\/>(new Throwable(s"can't find record for person with id = $id))
  } yield p
```

---

If you instead need to mix the two, you can do something like

```
def test : \/[Throwable,Person] = \/.fromTryCatch {
  mayThrow()

  val res = for {
    p <- q.firstOption.\/>(new Throwable("can't find record for person with id ="+id))
  } yield p

  res match {
    case \/-(p) => p
    case -\/(e) => throw e
  }
}
```

or better, you can separate the scopes and use `fromTryCatch` only when necessary, something like

```
def test : \/[Throwable,Person] =
  for {
    _ <- \/.fromTryCatch { mayThrow() } 
    p <- q.firstOption.\/>(new Throwable("can't find record for person with id ="+id))
  } yield p
```

Comment: as mentioned in original post `for`comprehension is not the only thing I have in `\/.fromTryCatch` as a matter for is a new block I am adding right now. existing logic in `\/.fromTryCatch` has other code which can throw exception (one example is it has a call to `.toInt` ) (this is just one example but there are other potential code blocks in original `\/.fromTryCatch` which has potential to throw exception so it's not only limited to `for` comprehension

Comment: Could you maybe include the imports you're using? I'm learning scalaz and ran across this. `\/>` where does this come from (can't really google that), thanks.